# Using BIRT 2.3.0 Report Designer with HSqlDB version 1.7

Tags: birt, hsqldb

We are trying to use BIRT 2.3.0 Report Designer with HSqlDB version 1.7

On clicking on the "Test Connection" we get a Connection Successful message.
However, on clicking on the "Data Set" menu item we get a message "No Tables
found".

We have placed the "hsqldb.jar" in the location
"plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc-230.v20080610/drivers"

Any help would be appreciated.

Diptendu Dutta

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB version 1.7 is about 8 years old. Try version 1.8.1.3 which works with JDK 1.4 and above, or version 2.0 which works with JDK 1.5 and 1.6.
This link indicates that you should add the JDBC driver using a wizard 
http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/build/